# Not be informed / not being informed?

Tags: tenses

Good morning! 
First of all, I'm not a native speaker and i'd like to know which sentence is correct and why.

"I hate you for not be informed"
"I hate you for not being informed"

In my opinion, I "feel" like the second one is the right one, but I can't tell my friend why the first one is not correct. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm closevoting this for be Too Basic.

Comment: We don't know what you're trying to say. So we cannot tell you what's the correct way to say it.

Comment: It might well be that the idea that the writer is trying to express is closer to "I hate for you to be uninformed"—where the thing hated is not the uninformed person but the fact that the person is uninformed.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition "for" needs to be followed by a noun. Therefore, the auxiliary verb "be" has to become a gerund "being", transforming it to a noun in order to make this sentence grammatically correct.

Ex:

I love you for taking care of me whenever I am in trouble.
I hate you for yelling at me all the time with no reason.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have misheard a common phrase,

> "I would hate for you not to be informed."

This means I would be very unhappy if you did not receive certain information.